# What is making this DIV height so big?

Tags: html, css

I cannot for the life of me find why this div height is so tall : http://www.imvu-e.com/forum/ referring to the DIV id `page-header`.

How it looks now:

[image]

How I wish it looked:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `clear:right` no `both` in this class:

```
span.corners-bottom {
    background-image: none;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    margin: 0 -5px;
    clear: right;
}
```

Take a look here about [Clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)